# Variations de « voir + infinitif »

Tags: grammaire, infinitif, auxiliaires, verbes-de-perception

En français on peut utiliser une construction « voir + infinitif ». *Voir* devient alors une sorte d'auxiliaire. Et ça marche avec quelques autres verbes aussi. On peut dire :

- Je le vois partir
- Je l'entends venir
- Je le regarde manger
- Je l'écoute parler

Maintenant, on peut aussi vouloir varier les verbes. Ne pas mettre toujours « voir », mais mettre des verbes plus précis « apercevoir », « repére », « aviser »... Cependant, je pense que la construction avec l'infinitif ne marche pas dans ce cas. Je pense qu'on peut dire « Je le vois partir » mais pas « Je l'aperçois partir ». Je suis en train de corriger le texte d'un ami, qui emploie ces constructions, et j'ai toujours tendance à remplacer, par exemple en « Je l'aperçois qui part ». Mais ce n'est que mon avis et, après pas mal de recherche sur le web, je n'ai pas réussi à le corroborer officiellement.

Deux questions :

1. ai-je raison de supposer que « Je l'aperçois partir » est erroné ?
2. si c'est le cas, y a-t-il une référence fiable à ce sujet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Je l'aperçois partir*

ne me choque pas. On trouve quelques rares occurrences de cette tournure, par exemple :

> *...: dès qu'il **aperçut partir** le carrosse, il se précipita tellement pour le suivre, qu'il laissa tomber son épée qu'il portait sous son bras...*

Histoire de Mr. Bertin, Marquis de Fratteaux, Compte d'H***, 1756

> *Je l'aperçois manger*

est moins heureux mais pas impossible. Je m'attendrais quand même plutôt à :

> *Je l'aperçois en train de manger*.

> *Je le repère partir*

ne semble pas possible et

> *je le repère qui part*

est douteux. Ici aussi, d'autres tournures seraient idiomatiques.

> *Je le repère en train de partir.*
>
> *Je le repère alors qu'il part.*

*Aviser* doit être suivi de la préposition *de* avant un infinitif :

> *Je l'avise de partir* (*de parler, d'être à l'heure, etc.*)

En dehors des auxiliaires *être* et *avoir*, certains verbes, dont les verbes [modaux](http://Verbe_modal) (semi-auxiliaires), peuvent donc être directement suivis d'un infinitif en tant que complément. J'ai trouvé dans [cette page](http://www.connectigramme.com/preposition.html/verbes-prep.html) la liste que voici :

```
adorer         descendre      laisser        rentrer   
affirmer       désirer        monter         retourner  
aimer          détester       nier           revenir  
aller          devoir         user           savoir   
apercevoir     écouter        paraître       sembler 
assurer        emmener        partir         sentir   
avoir beau     entendre       penser         sortir   
avouer         entrer         pouvoir        souhaiter   
compter        envoyer        préférer       venir 
courir         espérer        prétendre      voir 
croire         faillir        se rappeler    vouloir             
daigner        faire          reconnaître  
déclarer       falloir        regarder
```

Comment: Pour aviser, il s'agit du sens 3 ici : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aviser  donc on n'est pas tout à fait dans le cadre que tu cites. Pour le reste, merci pour l'avis, la liste et la référence. Il semble que apercevoir soit une exception qui fonctionne mais que les autres substituts de "voir" ne passent pas... Dans le texte que je corrige, le dernier cas en date est "Il le surprit lancer un regard à...". Avec voir, "Il le vit lancer un regard à..." ça aurait marché, mais là, j'ai corrigé.

Comment: Je n'avais pas envisagé ce sens d'aviser qui me paraît excessivement rare (cf. TLF i: vieilli et littéraire). Sinon, j'ajouterais *observer* à la liste des substituts de voir possible : *nous l'observons grandir*. D'autre part, bien que le sens soit un peu différent, on pourrait aussi ajouter *imaginer* : *je l'imagine partir*.